# How to call a javascript function from webview xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to call a javascript function from my webview xamarin.android app. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, implement a custom **WebClient** (look at CustomWebClient inheritance model) which overrides the OnPageFinished (aka OnNavigationCompleted) default behaviout:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
webView.LoadUrl("http://yoururl.com");
SetContentView(webView);
```

And now you can invoke JS directly like

```
webView.EvaluateJavascript("JS code",null);
```

The second argument is a callback . Which is  a placeholder for the **javascript** result .You can also define the **JavascriptResult** as the following:

```
 public class JavascriptResult : Java.Lang.Object, IValueCallback
    {
        private TaskCompletionSource<string> source;

        public Task<string> JsResult => source.Task;

        public JavascriptResult()
        {
            source = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        }

        public void OnReceiveValue(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
            try
            {
                string res = ((Java.Lang.String)result).ToString();

                source.SetResult(res);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                source.SetException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```